# React DirectLine chat doesn't works. Cannot find source files

Tags: reactjs, botframework, chatbot, direct-line-botframework

Good morning to all, I'm new on BotFrameworkand React and I'm trying to embed my bot to my React website but it is not showing and I can see some errors on Node.js console.

I copied&pasted the sample on my code but now it needs the adaptiveCardsHostConfig and bot attribute, so I tried to add it and it fails.
Please, could you help me to know where I'm wrong?

First of all I executed `npm install botframework-webchat` command on console and then set the code above:

```
import { Chat } from 'botframework-webchat';
...
<Chat
    adaptiveCardsHostConfig={{ fontFamily: '"Myriad Pro", sans-serif' }}
    directLine={{ secret: 'asV4w25M-8I.cwA._-M.o-eAeWrQg0MMJcup3bU8klFEPiKoOhIPV8HZHytS0r0' }}
    user={{ id: 'userid', name: 'username' }}
    bot={{ id: 'botID', name: 'botName' }}
    resize="detect"
/>
...
```

These  are the warnings on node.js console:

```
WARNING in ./~/adaptivecards/lib/adaptivecards.js
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) Cannot find source file '../src/adaptivecards.ts': Error: Can't resolve '../src/adaptivecards.ts' in 'C:\Users\dsanchis\source\repos\Modern Atum\BackEnd\CP.ModernAtum.API\node_modules\adaptivecards\lib'
 @ ./~/botframework-webchat/built/Attachment.js 6:22-46
 @ ./~/botframework-webchat/built/BotChat.js
 @ ./app/src/components/Header/Header.tsx
 @ ./app/src/components/Layout/Layout.tsx
 @ ./app/src/components/Search/Search.tsx
 @ ./app/src/components/GroupsExplorer/GroupsExplorer.tsx
 @ ./app/src/index.tsx
 @ multi es6-promise whatwg-fetch ./app/src/index.tsx

WARNING in ./~/adaptivecards/lib/enums.js
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) Cannot find source file '../src/enums.ts': Error: Can't resolve '../src/enums.ts' in 'C:\Users\dsanchis\source\repos\Modern Atum\BackEnd\CP.ModernAtum.API\node_modules\adaptivecards\lib'
 @ ./~/adaptivecards/lib/adaptivecards.js 7:9-27
 @ ./~/botframework-webchat/built/Attachment.js
 @ ./~/botframework-webchat/built/BotChat.js
 @ ./app/src/components/Header/Header.tsx
 @ ./app/src/components/Layout/Layout.tsx
 @ ./app/src/components/Search/Search.tsx
 @ ./app/src/components/GroupsExplorer/GroupsExplorer.tsx
 @ ./app/src/index.tsx
 @ multi es6-promise whatwg-fetch ./app/src/index.tsx

WARNING in ./~/adaptivecards/lib/utils.js
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) Cannot find source file '../src/utils.ts': Error: Can't resolve '../src/utils.ts' in 'C:\Users\dsanchis\source\repos\Modern Atum\BackEnd\CP.ModernAtum.API\node_modules\adaptivecards\lib'
 @ ./~/adaptivecards/lib/adaptivecards.js 9:14-32
 @ ./~/botframework-webchat/built/Attachment.js
 @ ./~/botframework-webchat/built/BotChat.js
 @ ./app/src/components/Header/Header.tsx
 @ ./app/src/components/Layout/Layout.tsx
 @ ./app/src/components/Search/Search.tsx
 @ ./app/src/components/GroupsExplorer/GroupsExplorer.tsx
 @ ./app/src/index.tsx
 @ multi es6-promise whatwg-fetch ./app/src/index.tsx

WARNING in ./~/adaptivecards/lib/host-config.js
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) Cannot find source file '../src/host-config.ts': Error: Can't resolve '../src/host-config.ts' in 'C:\Users\dsanchis\source\repos\Modern Atum\BackEnd\CP.ModernAtum.API\node_modules\adaptivecards\lib'
 @ ./~/adaptivecards/lib/adaptivecards.js 8:9-33
 @ ./~/botframework-webchat/built/Attachment.js
 @ ./~/botframework-webchat/built/BotChat.js
 @ ./app/src/components/Header/Header.tsx
 @ ./app/src/components/Layout/Layout.tsx
 @ ./app/src/components/Search/Search.tsx
 @ ./app/src/components/GroupsExplorer/GroupsExplorer.tsx
 @ ./app/src/index.tsx
 @ multi es6-promise whatwg-fetch ./app/src/index.tsx

WARNING in ./~/adaptivecards/lib/text-formatters.js
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) Cannot find source file '../src/text-formatters.ts': Error: Can't resolve '../src/text-formatters.ts' in 'C:\Users\dsanchis\source\repos\Modern Atum\BackEnd\CP.ModernAtum.API\node_modules\adaptivecards\lib'
 @ ./~/adaptivecards/lib/card-elements.js 16:21-49
 @ ./~/adaptivecards/lib/adaptivecards.js
 @ ./~/botframework-webchat/built/Attachment.js
 @ ./~/botframework-webchat/built/BotChat.js
 @ ./app/src/components/Header/Header.tsx
 @ ./app/src/components/Layout/Layout.tsx
 @ ./app/src/components/Search/Search.tsx
 @ ./app/src/components/GroupsExplorer/GroupsExplorer.tsx
 @ ./app/src/index.tsx
 @ multi es6-promise whatwg-fetch ./app/src/index.tsx

WARNING in ./~/adaptivecards/lib/card-elements.js
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) Cannot find source file '../src/card-elements.ts': Error: Can't resolve '../src/card-elements.ts' in 'C:\Users\dsanchis\source\repos\Modern Atum\BackEnd\CP.ModernAtum.API\node_modules\adaptivecards\lib'
 @ ./~/adaptivecards/lib/adaptivecards.js 6:9-35
 @ ./~/botframework-webchat/built/Attachment.js
 @ ./~/botframework-webchat/built/BotChat.js
 @ ./app/src/components/Header/Header.tsx
 @ ./app/src/components/Layout/Layout.tsx
 @ ./app/src/components/Home/Home.tsx
 @ ./app/src/components/GroupsExplorer/GroupsExplorer.tsx
 @ ./app/src/index.tsx
 @ multi es6-promise whatwg-fetch ./app/src/index.tsx
```

And here the error on Chrome Console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: action$.ofType(...).map(...).filter(...).throttleTime is not a function
        at sendTypingEpic (app.bundle.js:10062)
        at app.bundle.js:78455
        at Array.map (<anonymous>)
        at app.bundle.js:78454
        at MapSubscriber.project (app.bundle.js:78520)
        at MapSubscriber._next (app.bundle.js:27998)
        at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (app.bundle.js:3631)
        at Subject.next (app.bundle.js:8134)
        at app.bundle.js:78530
        at app.bundle.js:78646
```

---

### UPDATE(15/05/2018):

Now DirectLine component renders on page, but it has not proper style and I can't apply a style, just set with and height. It shows like below (with a transparent background, chooser file button and field...):
[DirectLine bot showed without proper style](https://prnt.sc/ji2891)

The warnings on Node.js console still appearing and now in Chrome console I can see a new error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null
    at e.componentDidUpdate (botchat.js:34)
    at t.notifyAll (botchat.js:34)
    at r.close (botchat.js:34)
    at r.closeAll (botchat.js:20)
    at r.perform (botchat.js:20)
    at o.perform (botchat.js:20)
    at o.perform (botchat.js:20)
    at Object.S [as flushBatchedUpdates] (botchat.js:20)
    at r.closeAll (botchat.js:20)
    at r.perform (botchat.js:20)
```

How can I solve the styles and add custom?

Comment: I leverage an empty react app via https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app and integrate Bot web chat, which works fine. And according your error message, could you double check whether you have installed the package successfully?

Comment: I executed `npm install botframework-webchat` again and tried executing `npm install adaptivecards` in order to solve the warnings showed in node.js console but nothing is solved.

Comment: Crosslinking to GitHub post for other users who might have this question: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/974

Answer (score 1):

It's due to the `.map` files in the output (in the `lib` and `dist` folders). Remove them and you get rid of the webpack warnings.

Also see reported issue here: https://github.com/Microsoft/AdaptiveCards/issues/1492